# How to efficiently add items to collection with firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of tags that I would like to add to a firestore collection.

If I'm not misunderstanding the approach I have here, I think I'm making individual adds to the collection when I think it would be more efficient to 'group' them and set them all at once. Is something like this possible? Also would it be possible to add the document to the workouts collection at the same time?

Right now I'm looking at tags.length + 1 writes to firebase for every call to this function. I'd like to reduce that as much as possible.

```
logWorkoutAsync({ userId, timeStamp, tags }){
    var db = this.firebase.firestore();

    return db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('workouts').add({
        timeStamp,
        'class': false
    }).then(doc => {

        var tagsCollection = doc.collection('tags')

        var promises = []

        tags.forEach(t => {
            promises.push(tagsCollection.doc(t.id.toString()).set(t))
        })

        return Promise.all(promises)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cloud Firestore has support for batched writes, see the docs here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

So you could do something like this:

```
logWorkoutAsync({ userId, timeStamp, tags }){
    var db = this.firebase.firestore();

    return db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('workouts').add({
        timeStamp,
        'class': false
    }).then(doc => {

        var tagsCollection = doc.collection('tags');

        // Begin a new batch
        var batch = db.batch();

        // Set each document, as part of the batch
        tags.forEach(t => {
            var ref = tagsCollection.doc(t.id.toString());
            batch.set(ref, t);
        })

        // Commit the entire batch
        return batch.commit();
    })
}
```

Comment: Woah! This is awesome! Could I include the initial .add in the batch too? Maybe if I do something like batch.set(db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('workouts').doc(timeStamp.toString), { timeStamp, 'class': false }) ? I just have to provide an 'id' in this case, right?

Comment: Yes you can definitely do that!  You can add up to 500 operations in a batch.  And your intuition is correct, to get `batch.add()` you need to do a `.doc()` elsewhere to create the reference and then call `batch.set()` on that reference.

Comment: @hatboysam And what we can do in case that we want to write more than 500 operations in a single batch? It's possible to concatenate more than once ? I mean, have 2 batches, one with 500 ops and another one with 250 .. and so on

Comment: You can do as many batches as you want as long as you don't put more than 500 operations in each.  You will just have to keep a counter in your app.

Comment: @hatboysam How do you 'add' to a collection rather than 'set'? Use case: Add multiple documents to a collection using system generated key.

Comment: @Amsakanna `let ref = db.collection('collection').doc('newItem'); db.batch().set(ref, {});`

Comment: @Amsakanna were you able to figure out the way to 'add' to the collection rather than 'set'? I'm also stuck with the similar use case.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Sadly, no!

Comment: @Amsakanna I used the short-unique-id package to generate a "firebase like" id and that worked for me
`const ref = db.collection('collection').doc(uid.randomUUID(20)); 
db.batch().set(ref, {});`

Comment: @RonChan Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: For anyone looking to do the same as @Amsakanna without another external package like in  @ron-chan's solution. You can now do this instead: `const ref = db.collection('collection').doc();  db.batch().set(ref, {});` as calling `.doc()` with no arguments generates a random id just like add.

Answer (score 8):

IF you want to add multiple documents to collection you could do something like this which worked fine for me since I was stuck in a similar case.

```
let colRef = db.collection('cars')

/// Batch Thing //
var batch = db.batch();

let cars = [{name: 'Audi', model: 'A8'}, {name: 'BMW', model: '730'}]
cars.forEach(c => {
  let ref = colRef.doc(`${c.name}`)
  batch.set(ref, {
    name: `${c.name}`,
    model: `${c.model}`
  })
})

return batch.commit()
  .then(data => {
    console.log('good')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('there is an error')
  })
```